# Using maven profiles to configure code based a Spring application

Tags: properties-file, spring-4, maven-profiles

I have a Spring application which is complete code based configured. And I am trying to combine maven profiles to setup my db connections. I defined some properties for a local, live and staging issues. Now I try to get control over maven profiles. Every profil defines my MySql db connection params. Here my current setup:

local.properties-file:

```
mysql.username=test
mysql.password=test
mysql.databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
mysql.databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

pom.xml

```
...
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>live</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filterFile>src/main/config/live.properties</filterFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filterFile>src/main/config/local.properties</filterFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <filterFile>src/main/config/staging.properties</filterFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
...
```

ApplicationConfig

```
...
@Value("${mysql.username}")
    private String username;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        ..

        return dataSource;
    }
...
```

Problem here is that my properties aren't loaded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a property called `filterFile` during the maven build, but you actually need to get the value into your application, which you'll then have to use to look up the file to load.

A potentially better way of doing this is to define the variable values as properties in your pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>live</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <mysql.username>test</mysql.username>
            <mysql.password>test</mysql.password>
            <mysql.databaseUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</mysql.databaseUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- ... -->
</profiles>
```

Then enable resource filtering:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

In a file, e.g. `persistence.properties`:

```
mysql.username=${mysql.username}
mysql.password=${mysql.password}
mysql.databaseUrl=${mysql.databaseUrl}
mysql.databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Finally, load the properties file and create your datasource:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence.properties"})
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("mysql.username"));
        // ...
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```